# How to have a default selected value for angularjs 1.5 programmatically

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I want to add a "Select a bank" option in the dropdown. I Only want that option to be selected if there is more than 1 item in the list (banks). This is the code:

This is what I current have:

```
<select class="form-control" name="bankName" id="field_bankName"
        ng-model="vm.bankAccount.bankName"
        ng-options="banks as banks.description for banks in vm.items.banks track by banks.id"
        required>
  <option selected="selected" value="" disabled="">Select a bank</option>
</select>
```

However, I want the only (first) option in the list to be selected if the list only has 1 item on it.

I tried to do multiple things, but none seem to work, from having an `ng-selected` with a `banks.length > 1` expression inside however I Cannot add an expression to the ng-options for every "option" that is something like `ng-selected="banks.length == 1"`.

Can you please point me to the best approach for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `vm.bankAccount.bankName` in the controller:

```
if (vm.banks.length == 1) {
    vm.bankAccount.bankName = vm.banks[0];
} else {
    vm.bankAccount.bankName = null;
};
```

Comment: I did do it after a while but still gonna mark your answer as accepted cause it was similar to what I did